sudo apt update doesn't work - 404 Not Found
When I try to run the sudo apt update command it gives me this error:

Does someone how to solve this?

Having so many mixed repositories is not really recommended. You also have 10 as noble and others as jammy which can lead to issues. You will need to learn to resolve repository issues when ever you get them.

The kazam PPA is not available for your version of Ubuntu, hence this error.
Remove the ppa with
sudo add-apt-repositories --remove ppa:kazam-team/stable-series

You can install kazam from the official repositories instead.
sudo apt install kazam

